# Meaning of nom. voltage for terminal blocks

Tags: voltage, plc

If the nom. voltage of a terminal block is i.e. 500 V, will it still function properly with only 24 V? For example this one: [PT 1,5/S-QUATTRO - Feed-through terminal block](https://www.phoenixcontact.com/en-pc/products/feed-through-terminal-block-pt-15-s-quattro-3208197)

For a project I need terminal blocks to create connections between sensors which I plan to power with 24 V DC from the PLC.

Comment: Locate the proper data sheet and check the meaning of the numbers in it. If no pdf data sheet available, choose a part that has one.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly.

500 V would be the max working voltage allowed without breakdown, either from tracking or dielectric breakdown of the plastic.

You can use any voltage you want up to and including 500 V.

Comment: Thank you, how come they would make something like this with only 24 nom. v then?https://www.phoenixcontact.com/en-pc/products/feed-through-terminal-block-pt-25-quattro-la-24-rd-3210280

Comment: That particular product has an LED and resistor intended for 24V. While the terminal block itself is certainly rated for higher voltage, anything much larger than 24V would fry the LED.